# Is there a way to get the dtype of a pyspark.sql.column.Column without first calling it on a pyspark.sql.DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This might be a niche question, but imagine that you have a `udf` defined like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
import pyspark.sql.types as st
@sf.udf(returnType=st.ArrayType(st.StringType()))
def some_function(text: str) -> List[str]:
    return text.split(' ')
```

This returns an `udf`, of which I need to know it's `returnType`. Is there a way to get the return type:

- **Without** calling the udf on a pyspark.sql.DataFrame and using the dtypes() function on the result
- **Without** storing the `returnType` for this function in a separate place

Context:
I want to give an `.alias` to the `pyspark.sql.column.Column` that is returned by the `udf`, but the alias should depend upon its type.

So in dummy code the desired result would be:

```
input_column_name = 'some_text_column'
expr = some_udf_function(sf.col(input_column_name))
dtype_abbreviation = get_dtype_return_type_abbreviation(expr) 
expr_renamed = expr.alias(input_column_name + '_' + dtype_abbreviation)
```

Where the desired return of `get_dtype_return_type_abbreviation` would be for example 'list_of_strings' for an `udf` that returns `st.ArrayType(st.StringType())`. The alias in this case would be 'some_text_column_list_of_lists'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `returnType` property of the udf

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf
import pyspark.sql.types as st
from typing import List

@sf.udf(returnType=st.ArrayType(st.StringType()))
def some_function(text: str) -> List[str]:
    return text.split(' ')

print(some_function.returnType)

# output
ArrayType(StringType,true)
```